# Google map above bottom sheet in Flutter

Tags: android, google-maps, flutter, flutter-layout, bottom-sheet

I have a map view and lots of markers which will be added to the map after fetching items through the api. 
also i have a `DraggableScrollableSheet` which is inside a stack with GoogleMap, user can drag the sheet to the top with a fraction that the map will be visible a bit above the sheet.

when user selects an item through the list from the sheet , map will animate to the items marker. the problem occurs here that the selected Marker is hidden behind the sheet and i want to change the bounding box of the map to just show the available area.

i have tried `getVisibleRegion` from Google map controller and animated the camera with new bounding box but it seems that the whole map behind the sheet is also considered as visible region.

also tried wraping GoogleMap with a padding and animate the map bottom padding regarding scroll of the sheet, it works but terrible on performance is there any other way should i try?